# Explanation of Meta data commit phase in Oracle ADF framework

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

What role is `meta data commit phase` playing  during request life cycle phase of a ADF faces component ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try googling:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/adfmds-128339.pdf

And reading the docs?